# How to implement multiple Routers with similar asURLRequest()

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have been working to re-implement a healthy network layer in our app and Routers are noted in many tutorials / Alamofire documentation. The app has a lot of endpoints, to keep things readable I want to split them out into their subset of services. That was also noted as a best practice.

The very first endpoint that I implemented works perfectly fine, but, when I create another Router there is the asURLRequest() function which would pretty much be a duplicate. The only difference *could* be the switch/case. Otherwise its almost certain to be the same.

To do this in Kotlin or Java, I would create a class and extend the function calling the super. Im not certain how that works here in Swift.

```
enum AuthenticationRouter: URLRequestConvertible {
    
    case login(username:String, password:String)
    
    // MARK: - HTTPMethod
    private var method: HTTPMethod {
        switch self {
        case .login:
            return .get
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Path
    private var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .login:
            return "users/login"
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Parameters
    private var parameters: Parameters? {
        switch self {
        case .login:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - URLRequestConvertible
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = try K.TestServer.baseURL.asURL()
        
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
        
        // HTTP Method
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        
        // Common Headers
        urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.acceptType.rawValue)
        urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.contentType.rawValue)
        
        switch self {
        case .login(let username, let password):
            // Handle adjusting headers or request as needed
        default: ()
        }
        
        // Parameters
        if let parameters = parameters {
            do {
                urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
            } catch {
                throw AFError.parameterEncodingFailed(reason: .jsonEncodingFailed(error: error))
            }
        }
        
        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using inheritance/protocols ? Creating a base router class / protocol that implements the asUrlRequest() function? Each other router will have its own params/conformance to the other parts of the Alamofire protocol

Answer (score 0):

Here is and old code I used. I’d change the base class to protocol instead and continue your usage of enums that conforms to that protocol I like it much better.

```
import Alamofire

protocol API {
    var method: HTTPMethod { get }
    var encoding: ParameterEncoding? { get }
    var parameters: Parameters { get }
    var headers: HTTPHeaders { get }
    var timeout:TimeInterval { get }
    var path: String { get }
    var baseUrl: String { get }
}

class Router: API {
    var method: HTTPMethod { .get }

    var encoding: ParameterEncoding? { JSONEncoding.default }

    var parameters: Parameters {
        let params = Parameters()
        return params
    }

    var headers: HTTPHeaders {
        let headers = HTTPHeaders()
        // TODO - add defualt headers if needed
        return headers
    }

    var timeout: TimeInterval {
        #if DEBUG
            return 120
        #else
            return 30
        #endif
    }

    var path: String {
        fatalError("Must be overridden in subclass")
    }

    var baseUrl: String { Consts.serverUrl }

}

extension Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    open func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        guard let baseURL = URL(string: baseUrl) else { throw someError }
    
        let appendedURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
        let urlRequest = try URLRequest(url: appendedURL, method: method)
    
        guard let encoder = encoding else { throw someError }
    
        var eUrlRequest = try encoder.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
        eUrlRequest.timeoutInterval = timeout
        headers.forEach { eUrlRequest.addValue($0.value, forHTTPHeaderField: $0.name) }
        return eUrlRequest
    }
}
```

And then an example UserRouter would be

```
import Alamofire

final class UserRouter: Router {

    enum Endpoint {
        case signIn(userName: String, password: String)
    }

    let endpoint: Endpoint

    init(endpoint: Endpoint) {
        self.endpoint = endpoint
    }

    override var method: HTTPMethod {
        .get
    }

    override var parameters: Parameters {
        var params = super.parameters
        switch endpoint {
        case .signIn(let userName, let password): 
            params[“login”] = [“username”: userName, “password”: password]
        }
        return params
    }

    override var path: String {
        switch endpoint {
        case .signIn:
            return "/signIn"
        }
    }
}
```

In this way the asUrlRequest() function will be used throughout the code (; the Alamofire.Session().request() function will accept the each one of the routers.

Additionally, there is a great open-source abstraction that does similar work above Alamofire. Moya - https://github.com/Moya/Moya.
It supports Combine and RxSwift right out of the box

Comment: HI,
I implemented what you indicated, but I have a problem.
I don't understand how within my ViewModel I can then invoke the router

Comment: Something like: in your VM - func someVMFunc() {
 let r = UserRouter(endpoint: .signIn(userName: “myUser”, password: “myPassword”); AF.request(r) { response in print(response) }